# Set screen to log every session

Tags: sudo, 16.10, session

I have installed an Ubuntu server, I'v added some user, and I've added some of them to the *sudoers* group to gain root access. This is not a production server, this is just a sandbox for our developers.

One of them is installed screen, what is very useful tool, I use it also.

Usually other users ask me, when they do something, install a new package, or modify something, but I want to check sometimes what they did behind the screen.

Is it possible to set globally to log screen sessions separated by user?

For example, like `.bash_history` in home directory.

(I did not find the proper tag for screen, please edit)